# Security issue after migrating DataTransformer to StateProvider

Tags: security, migration, api-platform.com, symfony6

#### API Platform 2.6

I have the following operation in my current code, using a DataTransformer + a Symfony voter for security:

```php
#[ApiResource(
    itemOperations: [
        'contents' => [
            'security' => 'is_granted("FRIDGE_READ", object)',
            'method' => 'get',
            'path' => '/fridges/{id}/contents',
            'output' => FridgeContents::class,
        ],
    ],
)]
class Fridge {}
```

```php
class FridgeContentsOutputDataTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function supportsTransformation($data, string $to, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return FridgeContents::class === $to && $data instanceof Fridge;
    }

    public function transform($fridge, string $to, array $context = []): FridgeContents
    {
        // ...transform data...

        return $fridgeContents;
    }
}
```

The voter responsible for the `FRIDGE_READ` attribute receives the `Fridge` instance as subject, allowing me to only grant access to users who own that fridge.

#### API Platform 2.7

Now that DataTransformers are being deprecated, I refactored it to a StateProvider, as stated in the doc:

```php
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(
            uriTemplate: '/fridges/{id}/contents',
            security: 'is_granted("FRIDGE_READ", object)',
            output: FridgeContents::class,
            provider: FridgeContentsProvider::class,
        ),
    ],
)]
class Fridge {}
```

```php
class FridgeContentsProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly ProviderInterface $itemProvider,
    ) {
    }

    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): FridgeContents
    {
        /** @var Fridge $fridge */
        $fridge = $this->itemProvider->provide($operation, $uriVariables, $context);

        // ...transform data...

        return $fridgeContents;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is intended, but my voter is no longer receiving the `Fridge` instance here, but the output `FridgeContentsItem` object.

Is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

#### Possible workaround

I moved the security check to my StateProvider, but now my security is scattered between resources & providers...

```php
    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): FridgeContents
    {
        /** @var Fridge $fridge */
        $fridge = $this->itemProvider->provide($operation, $uriVariables, $context);
        
        if (!$this->security->isGranted('FRIDGE_READ', $fridge)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to try `securityPostDenormalize` (with `security`) but I'm not sure

```php
uriTemplate: '/fridges/{id}/contents',
security: 'is_granted("FRIDGE_READ", object)',
securityPostDenormalize: 'is_granted("FRIDGE_READ", object)',
output: FridgeContents::class,
```

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-security/api-property